# Error in installing Python package PCAPY

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install a pcapy using pip but I am getting this error

```
C:\Users\mshaik>pip install pcapy
Collecting pcapy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/68/b49e008f9e2b5ab727fb4b820c2e7d0914bd8dacb3c2d668a36b6e5d8991/pcapy-0.11.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pcapy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pcapy ... error
  Complete output from command c:\tool\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mshaik\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-tz7hmn\\pcapy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\mshaik\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-3vllr5 --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pcapy' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapdumper.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapdumper.obj
  pcapdumper.cc
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tpbpfobj.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\bpfobj.obj
  bpfobj.cc
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapobj.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapobj.obj
  pcapobj.cc
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcap_pkthdr.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcap_pkthdr.obj
  pcap_pkthdr.cc
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapy.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.obj
  pcapy.cc
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tpwin32\dllmain.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32\dllmain.obj
  dllmain.cc
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\wpdpack\Lib\x64 /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 wpcap.lib packet.lib ws2_32.lib /EXPORT:initpcapy build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapdumper.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\bpfobj.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapobj.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcap_pkthdr.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32\dllmain.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pcapy.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.pyd.manifest
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.exp
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free referenced in function "void __cdecl pcap_dealloc(struct pcapdumper *)" (?pcap_dealloc@@YAXPAUpcapdumper@@@Z)
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl pcap_getattr(struct pcapdumper *,char *)" (?pcap_getattr@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAD@Z)
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl new_pcapdumper(struct pcap_dumper *)" (?new_pcapdumper@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcap_dumper@@@Z)
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl new_pcapdumper(struct pcap_dumper *)" (?new_pcapdumper@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcap_dumper@@@Z)
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dump(struct pcapdumper *,struct _object *)" (?p_dump@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
  pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dump(struct pcapdumper *,struct _object *)" (?p_dump@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAU1@@Z)
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_filter(struct bpfobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_filter@@YAPAU_object@@PAUbpfobject@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
  pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
  bpfobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_New referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_get_bpf(struct bpfobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_get_bpf@@YAPAU_object@@PAUbpfobject@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_New
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ValueError referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl err_closed(void)" (?err_closed@@YAPAU_object@@XZ)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_RestoreThread referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_next(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_next@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_SaveThread referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_next(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_next@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords referenced in function "void __cdecl PythonCallBack(unsigned char *,struct pcap_pkthdr const *,unsigned char const *)" (?PythonCallBack@@YAXPAEPBUpcap_pkthdr@@PBE@Z)
  pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyThreadState_Get referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dispatch(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_dispatch@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_Append referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl findalldevs(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?findalldevs@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@0@Z)
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItemString referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_NewException referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_GetDict referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddIntConstant referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddObject referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4 referenced in function _initpcapy
  pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Type referenced in function _initpcapy
  build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pcapy.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 22 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\mshaik\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

 Running setup.py clean for pcapy
Failed to build pcapy
Installing collected packages: pcapy
  Running setup.py install for pcapy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\tool\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mshaik\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-tz7hmn\\pcapy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mshaik\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-s5f0rz\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pcapy' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapdumper.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapdumper.obj
    pcapdumper.cc
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tpbpfobj.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\bpfobj.obj
    bpfobj.cc
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapobj.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapobj.obj
    pcapobj.cc
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcap_pkthdr.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcap_pkthdr.obj
    pcap_pkthdr.cc
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tppcapy.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.obj
    pcapy.cc
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\wpdpack\Include -Ic:\tool\python27\include -Ic:\tool\python27\PC /Tpwin32\dllmain.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32\dllmain.obj`enter code here`
    dllmain.cc
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    C:\Users\mshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\wpdpack\Lib\x64 /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\tool\python27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 wpcap.lib packet.lib ws2_32.lib /EXPORT:initpcapy build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapdumper.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\bpfobj.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapobj.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcap_pkthdr.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\win32\dllmain.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pcapy.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.pyd.manifest
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pcapy.exp
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free referenced in function "void __cdecl pcap_dealloc(struct pcapdumper *)" (?pcap_dealloc@@YAXPAUpcapdumper@@@Z)
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl pcap_getattr(struct pcapdumper *,char *)" (?pcap_getattr@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAD@Z)
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FindMethod
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl new_pcapdumper(struct pcap_dumper *)" (?new_pcapdumper@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcap_dumper@@@Z)
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl new_pcapdumper(struct pcap_dumper *)" (?new_pcapdumper@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcap_dumper@@@Z)
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dump(struct pcapdumper *,struct _object *)" (?p_dump@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    pcapdumper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dump(struct pcapdumper *,struct _object *)" (?p_dump@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapdumper@@PAU1@@Z)
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_filter(struct bpfobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_filter@@YAPAU_object@@PAUbpfobject@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
    pcap_pkthdr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
    bpfobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_New referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_get_bpf(struct bpfobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_get_bpf@@YAPAU_object@@PAUbpfobject@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_New
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ValueError referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl err_closed(void)" (?err_closed@@YAPAU_object@@XZ)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_RestoreThread referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_next(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_next@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_SaveThread referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_next(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_next@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords referenced in function "void __cdecl PythonCallBack(unsigned char *,struct pcap_pkthdr const *,unsigned char const *)" (?PythonCallBack@@YAXPAEPBUpcap_pkthdr@@PBE@Z)
    pcapobj.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyThreadState_Get referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl p_dispatch(struct pcapobject *,struct _object *)" (?p_dispatch@@YAPAU_object@@PAUpcapobject@@PAU1@@Z)
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_Append referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl findalldevs(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?findalldevs@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@0@Z)
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItemString referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_NewException referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_GetDict referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddIntConstant referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddObject referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4 referenced in function _initpcapy
    pcapy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Type referenced in function _initpcapy
    build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pcapy.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 22 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\mshaik\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I am just scratching head from past 3 days.

Any suggestion would really greatful!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below links for the error:

> https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2015-January/683753.html
>   https://www.falatic.com/index.php/120/a-guide-to-building-python-2-x-and-3-x-extensions-for-windows

Hope they will be helpful.

Comment: It shows for the windows 7 and I am using windows 10... Do you think its the same process for both??